# Vue - How to display the clicked item and the previous/next item of an array

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have two elements in two rows next to each other:

[image: Example radio station screenshot]

I have entered them all in an array of objects and called them through props to display them in the left one.

Now what I want to do is when I click on any channel from the left item, it shows in the right with the first item before it and after it in the array, so I am going to use `$emit` with `@clicked` function to get an event to call it on the `app.vue`. But I don't know what to do after to get it displayed.

I feel I should create a new component but I'm at a loss about the elements within.

Edit: Sorry I forgot to mention, the picture is the design not the result of my code, I could only create the left one "list of stations" and have a problem doing the right part based on a click of the left part

Comment: You need to include the relevant code

Comment: Your view already seems to know how to expand only one of the stations in the righthand list, since only one is expanded.  Did you do it this way: `<div v-if="index_in_this_list === expanded_index">Expanded content here` ?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, the picture is the design not the result of my code, I could only create the left one "list of stations" and have a problem doing the right part based on a click of the left part

Comment: You'll need to clarify your question a bit further - what are you hoping to achieve in your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed create 2 components. 1 component having a list of all the stations. another component displaying the details of the radio station.
The moment you click a station in the list, it sends an event and updates a property in the vue.app. This could for example be called selectedStation.
your component that shows the detail of the radiostation just receives a prop with the details of the station.

Comment: I know my dear sir that I can, I am just lost on how to do it, the exact code or the mechanics of it